# Checking version of cv2 in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7, opencv, python

I have recently just installed cv2 for python 3.7 on a Mac os (Mojave). I have no problems importing it, but when I try to check the version with

```
  cv2._version_
```

but I get

```
  AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '_version'
```

can anyone help? thanks!

Comment: try cv2.__version__

Comment: This worked, thanks! if you put this as an answer ill upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

`version` needs to have double underscores (`_`)

To check version via python (installed through pip)

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

To check version for homebrew installs:

```
brew info opencv
or
brew info opencv3
(depending on how you installed it)
```

Comment: How did you install opencv? Homebrew, pip, git, etc?

Comment: @AA1989 I've edited my answer to provide a way to check the opencv version if install by homebrew

Comment: I also have MacOS and cv2.__version__ (with two undersores) gives me the same error as op. Is there another way to check the version in python?